# MisFit API inegration not supporting in Outsystem InAppBrowser

Tags: cordova, google-authentication, inappbrowser, outsystems, misfit

I am using MisFit API in my crossplatform Android application which is developed in OutSystem. I am using InAppBrowser for the login process. But due to the Google restriction, I am getting the error "disallowed_useragent".

I have tried the cordova plugin versions 5.0.1,5.3.3,7.0.0. The issue is not resolved

I expect a way in which login to Misfit application can be done by clicking the Google Login button

Answer (score 0):

Add the below preference line in config.xml

```
<preference name="OverrideUserAgent" value="Mozilla/5.0 Google" />
```

Please note it solved my login with google issue in inappbrowser.
Thanks